# Expression Properties not accessible when it should be

Tags: c#, expression

I am using a GenericRepository pattern when accessing database using EF. I've been using this pattern for years now but it's the first time I have had this issue.

Everywhere in my program, I am able to access the expressions of other repositories implementing the generic one. However, in a particular service I am unable to access the Expression. Here is the code:

GenericRepository.cs

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public DbSet<TEntity> DbSet() => _context.Set<TEntity>();

    public async Task<TEntity> FirstOrDefaultAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> func, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
        await DbSet().FirstOrDefaultAsync(func, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

IGenericRepository

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    Task<TEntity> FirstOrDefaultAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> func, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}
```

AccountRepository (Where it works)

```
public class AccountRepository : GenericRepository<Account>, IAccountRepository
{
    public AccountRepository(DiscountedDbContext context) : base(context)
    { }
}

public interface IAccountRepository : IGenericRepository<Account>
{
}

...

public AccountManagementService(IAccountRepository accountRepository)
{
    Account account = await accountRepository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 1);
}
```

This is how it should look, I.E. showing properties:

[image]

And the implementation for the LocationRepository that does not work

```
 public class LocationRecordRepository : GenericRepository<LocationRecord>, ILocationRecordRepository
{
    public LocationRecordRepository(DiscountedDbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public interface ILocationRecordRepository : IGenericRepository<LocationRecord>
{
}

...

public GeoLocationService(ILocationRepository locationRepository)
{
     // ERROR IS HERE: Properties does not show up for the location repository
     LocationRecord current = await locationRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.);
}
```

This is all that appears when trying to access the model through expressions:

[image]

Here are the models:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Surname { get; set; }
    public string? Password { get; set; }
    public Guid StoreCode { get; set; }
}


public class LocationRecord
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateRecorded { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; } = null!;
    public string District { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Town { get; set; } = null!;
    public string PostCode { get; set; } = null!;
    public int Count { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

Comment: Here --GeoLocationService(ILocationRepository locationRepository)-- why didn't you use **ILocationRecordRepository** .

Comment: Seems you have ILocationRecordRepository and ILocationRepository and you think you use one while using another.

Comment: @Evk, that was just me copying/typing code with some inconsistencies. The problem was much simpler. I had a Migration called LocationRepository and it referenced the wrong one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple. I had a Migration called LocationRepository, and it referenced the wrong one.